# ASP.NET MVC 4: Select a default value for a DropdowlistFor used on a Strongly type view

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

Maybe the question was already asked, but the answer that i found is not clear.

I would like to select a Default Value of my Dropdown list.
I have a list of Countries and based on the Region Code retreive via Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, I would like to select the country of the user.

Will it be possible via my approach:

**View**

```
@model Question
@Html.DropDownListFor(b => b.SelectedAnswer,new SelectList(Model.Answers,"ID","Country"))
```

**Model**

```
 public class Question
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }

        public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int SelectedAnswer { get; set; }
        public int Order { get; set; }

        public Question()
        {
            Answers = new List<Answer>();
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to add this as a comment, but the length is too long, and this way if I'm helpful you can accept this as an answer.

This is the method I use to implement this;

First, within the viewmodel I have the following

```
public int FooID { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FooList { get; set; }
```

FooID being both the default value (or currently selected) and the property used to gather the post result.

I have a function to build FooList, which returns the type of 
List, using this format for each item:

```
new SelectListItem { Text = i.Name, Value = i.FooID.ToString() };
```

Before outputting the viewmodel, the current value is inserted into FooID, or if this is for a new item, I will generally set the value to 1, the default value.

Then for the output;

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FooID, Model.FooList)
```

Just remember that FooID will be passed over as a string, so will need to be gathered as a string FooID parameter, and converted to Int. As long as FooID is set before the viewmodel is passed to the view from the controller, the item within FooList whose value equals FooID will be set as the default ... Such as;

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        MyVM vm = new MyVM();
        vm.FooID = 1;
        vm.FooList = FunctionToGenerateFooList();

        return View(vm);
    }
```

Comment: Just like to point out I missed something fairly simple (I did this at first as well, I was looking in this file this morning and took a look, I completely forgot i had changed it)

A simpler solution would be instead of setting vm.FooID = 1 on the GET action, when building the list you can do this for the default value:

new SelectListItem { Text = i.Name, Value = i.FooID.ToString(), Selected = true};

Answer (score 0):

Really, you should be passing your dropdown list as a list holding SelectListItem. Then for each country, have the text as the country code and assign it an id within value. Then, when you initialise the model, gather the culture, and find which item within the list has a Text that matches

```
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;
```

and assign it's value property to SelectedAnswer.

Comment: Do you mean something like this : @Html.DropDownList("CountryID",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.Countries). I have used the ID to make a small test. And in the Controller: var query = db.Countries.Select(c => new { c.CountryID, c.Name }); ViewBag.Countries = new SelectList(query.AsEnumerable(), "CountryID", "Name", CountryId); But that doesn't work. If i'm using SelectedAnwser, it's not known for the mapping, if i'm using CountryID, it will not be retreive during the POST.